# How can I load files from httpdocs on the https side of the website

Tags: php, .htaccess, https

On my webserver. I have two directories which are publicly accessible. One of those is httpdocs/ and the other is httpsdocs/. You can probably guess where they're for.

The problem occurs when I wanted to create a CMS for myself. I want it to load the page with HTTPS for security reasons, but the problem is that my files are inside the httpdocs directory. I can move only the files for the system to the httpsdocs, but my next thought was what if I want a login on the normal website for people to login and view hidden content for not registered users?

Now my question is: Is there a way to combine those to directories so all the files will be inside the httpdocs and I can access them with the security HTTPS provides?

Things that you may need to know:

- The webserver runs php 5.2.9
- I only have FTP access to the webserver and to these directories.
- The server runs apache, so .htaccess is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a ton of avenues, but most are blocked if you can't alter the httpd.conf or certain restrictions are in place.

Your best bet would probably to simply abandon http: and just stick to https: and create a redirecting .htaccess in the http: folder. That way everything runs on a single directory.

Unless there is a drawback that would not allow your users to use HTTPS over HTTP.

Getting your ISP to make the https folder a symlink to the http folder would be the easiest solution here.

Comment: No, I can not alter the httpd.conf. I'll move some of the files to the HTTPS dir. But the main site will be on the HTTP. Once a form will be submitted, I'll switch to the HTTPS dir. The main reason I want to keep the HTTP is the website itself shouldn't be HTTPS while the viewers aren't supposed to login. Is it possible to use the same session in both directories?

Comment: Then the question is why not all in HTTPS? Is there a specific reason not to have all in HTTPS? Yes you can use the same sessions as long as you don't use the secure flag in the cookies setting or have different domains and the cookies set to specific domains.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The main reason is, like I said above, that the website itself should not run in HTTP. One of the reasons is that I load other items, like images, from different webpages. If I put the website itself in HTTPS the browser could notify the user of loading unsafe items from different locations. This is not a thing viewers aren't supposed to see.

Comment: If most of your site is in a subdirectory (or subdirectories) you could try running the other site with an alias definition in a htaccess file: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html But you could make your life easier if you can get your host to simply make the https folder a symlink to the http folder.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are likely using a hosting service that has things seperated. If this is the case then the answer is no, you can't combine these two directories into one. You can ask your provider if they can make that arrangement, but it would require changes to the apache configuration that you can't do.

That being said, barring the ability to have that configuration modified, the only other answer you are going to find is to move everything under the httpsdocs directory. Unless you can get another account setup or possibly if they offer the ability to setup subdomains with HTTPS connections. That would be an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try to move some of the files to the HTTPS dir, but I'll need to find another way to keep those data safe. The biggest problem is the passwords which will be send with the form.

Comment: The whole point of using SSL is the fact that it is an encrypted tunnel, in theory protecting the traffic within the tunnel from average attempts at stealing it. What data are you attempting to protect and what are you trying to protect it from?

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction. I am sending user names and passwords which I want to protect from man in the middle. But also other personal data I don't want to be known to others. Also the database settings and ftp settings will be send with the CMS. That is another reason the data should be send encrypted.

Comment: I still don't follow why just having everything travel over the SSL encrypted tunnel would be a problem. That's the point behind using it. Generally speaking, the reason that the entire site often isn't wrapped in SSL is not because its more secure to have only one part encrypted and separate fro the other, but because using SSL certs in that manner, depending on the level of traffic to your site, can add a small level of latency. Not to mention the cost of the Certs themselves. If you already have the certs, and are serving CMS data, it stands to reason everything should be encrypted.